# Can Payment Gateway hypothetically process a modified Apple Pay's transaction data

Tags: token, payment-gateway, applepay

I'm new to online payments. After some research, I wonder if Payment Gateway, by holding private key of `Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate` to decrypt Apple Pay payload data, can hypothetically modify it (e.g. change amount) and send modified request to other relevant parties (Acquirer, payment network, issuer ...) then ultimately charge user more than what authorized

Definitely if possible, they would not ever do it due to legal, reputation issues...I'm just wondering if it's possible technically

Comment: I feel there would be a check in there somewhere to prevent this, but can't definitively see where. One thing though, this isn't specific to Apple Pay, a Payment Gateway could do this with any type of payment, It would presumably show up quickly in receipts, money-withdrawn, etc

Comment: @mattfreake yeah agree. It probably could happen with credit card transactions also. Checking of receipt is when it already happened, however, not all customers check every single record in their transaction history

Comment: Yes, that's possible for a payment gateway. Because it responsible for decrypting payment token then send decrypted data to bank for authentication. That decrypted data contains the transaction amount in clear text, so it's possible to modify.

Comment: @KenChen For amount of transaction, I could only see Apple Pay Payment Token documentation mentioned that it was encrypted inside payload. So technically, a payment gateway can decrypt this payload then compare amount inside with amount submitted in plaintext together with API call.

For Google Pay, it seems that it doesn't content this transaction amount. I couldn't see any documentation mention about it

Comment: Yes there are encrypted amount and clear text amount in a payment token, and I think that's for payment gateways to double check the transaction correctness. After that actually when payment gateway send the decrypted token to banks, there is only one field containing amount.

Comment: @KenChen However, practice of double checking this amount seem to be not mandatory for all payment gateways. i tried Adyen and it did verify this amount matching. However when worked with another gateway, they said to me they won't verify and it's our responsibility to make sure the payment request sent is authorised and legit